# Polyfit degree from horizontal

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry, best-fit-curve

In my project, I have a best-fit line for some points which I got using `np.polyfit`. With that, I want to calculate the degree between the returned best-fit line and the horizon. As if the first point in the best-fit line were at the origin. Some of my misunderstanding comes from confusion of what polyfit returns. How best could I get the angle?

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had a small example of the code that you already wrote.

Comment: What is the meaning of "the degree between the returned best-fit line and the horizon"? Do you mean the angle of inclination of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
# simulate some data:
x = np.arange(10, dtype=np.float)
b = 1.5
y = 2 * x + b
# fit the data with a 1st degree polynomial
# (1st degree because poster mentions "best-fit *line*"):
cf = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
np.rad2deg(np.arctan(cf[0]))
```

It may be useful to watch https://www.brightstorm.com/math/precalculus/advanced-trigonometry/angle-inclination-of-a-line/ on how coefficients of the polynomial (cf[0] = m in the video) relate to the angle.

Comment: Awesome, that explains it exactly. The video was useful too.